# use R to loop through subdirectories and copy files

Tags: r, loops

I am trying to create a batch script in R to pre-process some data and one of the first steps I have to do is check to see if a file exists in a sub-directory and then (if it does) create a copy of it with a new name. I'm having trouble with the syntax.

This is my code:

```
##Define the subject directory path
sDIR = "/home/bsussman/Desktop/WORKSPACE"

#create data frame to loop through

##list of subject directories
subjects <-list.dirs(path = sDIR, full.names = TRUE, recursive = FALSE)


for (subj in 1:length(subjects)){
  oldT1[[subj]] <- dir(subjects[subj], pattern=glob2rx("s*.nii"), full.names=TRUE)
     T1[[subj]] <- paste(subjects[subj], pattern="/T1.nii",sep="")

  if (file.exists(paste(subjects[subj], pattern="/T1.nii",sep=""))=FALSE{
    file.copy(oldT1, T1)
  } 
}
```

It renames files in one subdirectory, but will not do loop through gives me these errors:

```
Error: unexpected '=' in:
"        
  if (file.exists(paste(subjects[subj], pattern="/T1.nii",sep=""))="
>     file.copy(oldT1, T1)
[1] FALSE
>   } 
Error: unexpected '}' in "  }"
> }
Error: unexpected '}' in "}"
```

I am not as much worried about the [1]FALSE message. But any ideas?

Thanks!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's just a problem with the syntax in the `if` statement. Try replacing this:

```
if (file.exists(paste(subjects[subj], pattern="/T1.nii",sep=""))=FALSE{
    file.copy(oldT1, T1)
}
```

with this:

```
if (!file.exists(paste(subjects[subj], pattern="/T1.nii",sep=""))){
    file.copy(oldT1, T1)
}
```